# Laravel: Database SSL connection not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssl

I tested the ssl connection with my (Open SSL) generated certificates via the MySQL workbench app and it was working perfectly fine via ssl. However, when I try to use a ssl connection to my remote database with Laravel I get errors. On my local machine I get a 502 Bad Gateway error when visiting my laravel website and on my online test setup  I get a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] error.
Config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'      => 'mysql',
            'host'        => env( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' ),
            'port'        => env( 'DB_PORT', '3306' ),
            'database'    => env( 'DB_DATABASE', 'forge' ),
            'username'    => env( 'DB_USERNAME', 'forge' ),
            'password'    => env( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' ),
            'unix_socket' => env( 'DB_SOCKET', '' ),
            'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'      => '',
            'strict'      => true,
            'engine'      => null,
            'modes'       => [
                //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
            'options' => [
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => base_path('ssl/client-key.pem'),
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => base_path('ssl/client-cert.pem'),
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path('ssl/ca-cert.pem')
            ]
        ],
```

This is an error that is logged in my online setup in the laravel log file:

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): Unable to locate peer certificate CN at /var/www/vhosts/website.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:38)

[stacktrace]
```

I'd really appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.